# Path Planning in a chaotic, ever-changing environment

Tags: path-finding

I've implemented Path Planning a few times, using [A* on nav meshes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm), and also [Continuum Crowds](https://grail.cs.washington.edu/projects/crowd-flows/) but now I am trying to plan paths in very chaotic environments.

In this environment, new routes and new blockages are created constantly, and chaotically. This is because the [environment is fully destructible](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C3bdi_gukXU), and the debris can create new obstacles.

In such an environment, nothing can be pre-computed. What would be a good way to sense the traversability in such a world? There is no concept of a grid in my world, b.t.w, but I wonder if I should introduce an artificial one for the purpose of planning.

But if navigation could be achieved without a grid, that would be much better of course.

Note that the navigation is not [merely dynamic](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/12186/real-time-dynamic-pathfinding) in the sense that certain transitions get opened/closed, but actually chaotic. This stops me from a simple approach of enabling/disabling certain edges on the navigation mesh. That approach would be usable if, e.g. a gate gets locked/unlocked. But in my case, in a blink of an eye, the routes could be drastically changed where simple mutations of a pre-computed mesh are not doable.

[image: An ever changing environment]

Comment: Must AI be able to recognize paths and move from a place to another at all costs? If not, you may rely onto other solutions to emulate the ability of moving around.

Comment: It doesn't have to always find the best path, it's fine if it is a little in-efficient, as long as it doesn't ignore obvious routes, or get stuck on an obstacle easily.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Real Time Dynamic Pathfinding?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/12186/real-time-dynamic-pathfinding) Note: there's a **lot** of variability in terms of possible problem constraints - if your problem is different than the link, please edit & draw attention to the differences.

Comment: When an agent needs to move, you can use a quick algorithm that moves in the general direction of the objective and avoids obstacles, meanwhile another system takes its time to figure out a path. This is the approach that the game Prototype takes. Of course you want it to react to a dynamic enviroment, or even work without complete knowledge, please take a look at goal oriented AI for inspiration. See also: [1](http://aigamedev.com/premium/interview/prototype-large-scale/) (paid membership required), [2](https://www.gdcvault.com/play/1022016/Getting-off-the-NavMesh-Navigating) (low volume).

Answer (score 1):

With a robotic system needing to plan its movements quickly in a dynamic environment I have seen [Rapidly-exploring random trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rapidly-exploring_random_tree) (or an adaption of them) being used for these approximations.

Comment: Out of curiosity - can you add some references to your claim? As far as I remember the original paper (and successors) make no mention of it - sounds rather aimed at navigation in high dimensional spaces.

Comment: @wondra Have only heard a presentation by someone working on this project. Now that I come to think of it, it may well be they oversimplified the problem for their audience.